# SharePoint Configuration Wizard Weird Behavior?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

After you have installed SharePoint you need to run the configuration wizard which typically asks what your Database server is what DB Name to use, what port to use for Central Admin, etc. Then it goes through its 1-9 install process...

Our problem is on one of our servers, which has a clean database, clean 12 hive, and no answer file is to be found (nor should it), the Configuration Wizard goes straight through to the 1-10 install process.  It doesn't ask any questions at all...

Why would this occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is expected if your server is already attached to a farm. Was the machine previously part of a SharePoint farm and removed via the farm's Central Admin? Was a clean SharePoint uninstall/reinstall performed?

Comment: Yes, we did a clean uninstall, removed 12 hive, removed registry keys, deleted all databases, and it still did it.  We have since then rebuilt the server and its working find now.  But would love to know why it was doing that, its a mystery...